# log4j how to load variable from properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I have `log4j.properties` in my project (WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties).

[image]

This file contain variable to my logs directory

```
LOG = D:/Logs/log4j
```

How can I load this variable in Java?
For example I want to do:

```
public static String logFolder = //TODO: get...("LOG")
```

Note: I'm using slf4j over log4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use java.util.Properties. A minimal example:

```
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));

    System.out.println("Value=" + prop.getProperty("LOG"));
  }
}
```